# How to get the selection of a jQuery UI Datepicker in a MVC Controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, datepicker

I have a MVC3 view with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#multiInlinePicker').datepick({
        multiSelect: 30, monthsToShow: 3, monthsToStep: 3,
        prevText: 'Prev months', nextText: 'Next months'
    });
   }

 <span id="multiInlinePicker"></span>
```

I would like to pass the selected dates on the datepick control to the controller. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance 
Regards Tom

Answer (score 2):

use `onselect`

```
$('#multiInlinePicker').datepick({
    multiSelect: 30, monthsToShow: 3, monthsToStep: 3,
    prevText: 'Prev months', 
    nextText: 'Next months',
    onSelect:function(date){ 
        //UPDATED
        $.ajax({
           url: 'url to your controller action',
           data:'selecteddate=' + date,
           type:'post',
           success:function(response){
              alert(reponse);
           }
        })

      }
});
```

NOTE: these calls your controllers action method everytime the date on datepicker is selected.. so make suure if u need that..

Comment: I can use this but I would like to pass the selected dates to the action method of the controller.

Comment: then use `ajax()` which points to the controller action method with a data (i.e date)...inside the `onSelect` option...